# Configure tableview cell to pass fetched object to another view (NSFetchedResultsController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

EDIT: Post heavily updated to support Mike A.'s `NSFetchedResultsController` methods, please see edit history for previous `NSFetchRequest` implementation.

I have a simple survey app with multiple `ViewControllers` -

```
StartViewController
InfoViewController
Q1ViewController
...
Q4ViewController
EndViewController
ResultsViewController
DetailsViewController
```

My `managedObject` is created on my `InfoViewController`:

```
// Identify the app delegate
MMUAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Use appDelegate object to identify managed object context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

// Create new managed object using the MMU entity description
NSManagedObject *ManagedObjectMMU;
ManagedObjectMMU = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MMU" inManagedObjectContext:context];

// Declare managed object
self.ManagedObjectMMU = ManagedObjectMMU;
```

Each view has buttons and text fields and a `navController`. When a button is selected or text entered, upon tapping the 'next' button on the navigation bar, each value gets saved in my `managedObject` like so:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
// error checks etc before
    [self.ManagedObjectMMU setValue:timeStamp forKeyPath:@"timeStamp"];
    [self.ManagedObjectMMU setValue:timeStamp forKeyPath:@"name"];
    [self.ManagedObjectMMU setValue:timeStamp forKeyPath:@"doB"];
// next viewcontroller pushed here
}
```

The `ManagedObjectMMU` gets passed through each view until it reaches the `ENDViewController` where it is saved to the `managedObjectContext`.

```
// Pass managed object to next ViewController
Q1.ManagedObjectMMU = self.ManagedObjectMMU;
```

Saving all results:

```
// Save managed object to managedObjectContext
NSError *error;
[[self.ManagedObjectMMU managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

My model is very basic, 10 attributes all of string type.

[image: Data Model]

Here is an example of a complete submission:

```
data: {
    dateOfBirth = "Sep 5, 1989";
    gender = Male;
    name = Ross;
    q1 = "Computing, Mathematics & Digital Technology";
    q2 = Yes;
    q3 = Football;
    q4 = "Commute From Home";
    q5 = Bicycle;
    status = University;
    timeStamp = "3/26/14, 2:56 PM";
}
```

The `ResultsViewController` is a `UITableView` of all results, each `cell.textLabel.text` containing the `name` of each submission, and the `cell.detailLabel.text` containing the `timeStamp`. I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the results from my model (please see Mike A.'s answer, I have implemented his methods).

[image: ResultsViewController]

What I want to happen is when the user taps on a cell, the fetched result object with that particular 'name' gets passed to the next view, displaying the data associated with that object (dataOfBirth, gender, q1,..., etc).

My question is: how can I pass the already fetched object to the next view to display all objects for that particular name? Can I display these specified objects on another `UITableView` or should I create some `UITextFields` and `Labels` to display the results? Should I pass the fetched object in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method or should I implement `prepareForSegue`? Sorry if this is a simple solution, I've searched online for days now and can't find a suitable solution! Thanks.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Mike A's suggestions and code snippets, I implemented the solution using the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MMU *results = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = results.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = results.timeStamp;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Pass fetched object to next ViewController
    detailView.ManagedObjectMMU = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
```

And the DetailView simply has some textfields and labels to display the questions and appropriate submissions for the object passed through from the cell:

```
- (void)displayDetails {
    self.nameDetail.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.genderDetail.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"gender"];
    self.dateOfBirthDetail.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
    self.statusDetail.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"status"];
    self.timeStampDetail.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];

    self.q1Answer.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"q1"];
    self.q2Answer.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"q2"];
    self.q3Answer.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"q3"];
    self.q4Answer.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"q4"];
    self.q5Answer.text = [_ManagedObjectMMU valueForKey:@"q5"];
}
```

I couldn't have done it without Mike A, please read through his answer and the comments below it if you want to understand the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an `NSFetchedResultsController` in each view controller. That way you don't have to deal with arrays in every view controller, only fetch requests. I would not recommend creating them in the App Delegate though. Preferably in each view controller or in a category.

So in your view controller try creating a property for an `NSFetchedResultsController` and implement its getter.

#### NSFetchedResultsController example

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:[self fetchRequest]
                                                                        managedObjectContext<# your managedObjectContext #>
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
        }
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and implement a method for your fetch request:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MMU"];

    // predicates, sort descriptors and other options go here...

    return fetchRequest
}
```

And then you can update your tableview data source by using

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count;
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MMU *results = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",results.name]; // Consider results.name without stringWithFormat.
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", results.timeStamp];

    return cell;
}
```

Now after you set up your view controller like this you update the model when you touch or place text somewhere. In your next view controller you can set up a new fetched results controller and a new fetch request, requesting the already changed data.

Depending on the number of view controllers you have, a better approach would be to subclass your UITableViewController to implement a fetched results controller by default and change the fetch request each time.

If this didn't help, please provide some more information about how you present your new view controllers and how you update your model.

## Update

You can pass each object from view controller to view controller by implementing either `prepareForSegue:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. In this case you will have to declare a public property in your header file for each view controller you want to pass the object to. Please note that implementing these methods you will be navigated to the next view controller by tapping a cell and not by the `IBAction` you provided in your example.

If you are using segues for pushing view controllers you can use the following example.

#### `prepareForSegue:` Example

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
   [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

   UIViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
   nextViewController.mmuModel = self.mmuModel; // The initial model that you have from InfoViewController.
}
```

This method will share your mmuModel with the next view controller. However you will need to update the model in each view controller separately.

This will get the job done, however CoreData is not meant to be used in such a way. CoreData is a powerful framework which usually does a lot of stuff for you. Another approach is to create a new `NSManagedObject` in `InfoViewController` like you do and then instead of passing the managed object in the question view controllers you can fetch it each time using an `NSFetchedResultsController` like I showed you. Only this time you will have to figure out a way of filtering the results so you can get the object you are looking for. There are multiple ways to do this, one approach would be to use some sort of id and maybe a predicate.

Moreover in your data model, instead of having everything in one entity (MMU), consider separating some things and using relationships.

Also it would be a good practive to different data types for your attributes i.e. timeStamp should be a Date, gender could be a BOOL if the only options are male, female, etc etc.

I hope this helped a bit. Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Thanks for replying! After some work and thanks to your code, I have implemented a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate the tableview and removed the array in my app delegate. I am still struggling to pass the specified object to the next tableview. You explained I need to set up a new `NSFetchedResultsController` on the next view requesting the already changed data, how can i do this? Currently, each cell is populated by the 'name' object, and upon tapping on a name, the next tableview should populate each cell with data related to that name object. Can you advise me on how to do this?

Comment: More specifically - `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` - What code goes here to pass the fetched results to the next tableview? Or should I implement prepareForSegue? And on the following tableview, `numberOfRowsInSection:` - I'm guessing I need to return the count of the passed fetched request here? Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I'm stuck on how to configure the cell here. I have searched online literally all night with no success, any advice you can give me is greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question with your data models (e.g. Question, Answer etc.). Moreover how are you updating your managed objects. If I understand correctly, you want when the user taps on a particular cell to relate to some changes in your model and present a new view controller with updated data based on that selection. If this is the case you need to get the object corresponding to the cell with `NSManagedObject *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have updated my question considerably to hopefully answer your questions about how my managed object is updated and saved. Your understanding of my question is correct, I would like when a cell is tapped, a new view is pushed displaying all information related to that object. I have outlined my question in more detail in the last few paragraphs of my post. Please let me know if you need more information, thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm still unable to display the data I want though. I can pass my `managedObject` to the `DetailView`, but I can't pass the already fetched results from the previous `ResultsView`. I think I need to rethink my whole logic behind my methods of persisting data. Your answer provided certainly is correct, so I have accepted it. I think it will be too much work trying to implement this so I will start from scratch again soon. Thanks a lot for your help though, much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem at all. One last thing to suggest is not to have your question strings in your views. This defies the whole MVC logic. I think it would be more preferable in this case to try to visualize your models as separate entities. For example a question is an separate entity and an answer could be another. And one question can  have one answer in this case (one-to-one relationship).  I assumed from your example that this was the case. Good luck and create a new thread if you are having trouble with the model setup.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Mike! I decided I'm too stubborn just to leave this issue and start over, so I stuck at it and finally got it working! Using your suggestions, I passed `detailView.ManagedObjectMMU = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` to the next view and can display my desired results :) I will take your other suggestions into consideration and try to implement them as best as I can. You've been a big help to me, thank you for your time and advice! Ross